# What is the difference between using を and に with the verb 注目する?

Tags: grammar

> 私たちは物価**を**注目しなかった。The price did not enter into our consideration.
>
> 誰も彼の見解**に**注目していないようだ。It seems that nobody takes any notice of his
>   opinions.

Comment: I'm not definite enough to post this as an answer, but I think it might possibly relate to direct object vs. indirect object. 'Nobody notices' vs. 'Nobody pays attention to'.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

～を注目する is much less common than ～に注目する (7 vs 195 instances on BCCWJ). Semantically, all the examples of ～を注目する on BCCWJ look completely interchangeable with ～に注目する to me. I think you can stick to ～に注目する.

[image: Results of ～を注目する on BCCWJ]

Answer (score 0):

私たちは物価を注目しなかった。The price did not enter into our consideration.

誰も彼の見解に注目していないようだ。It seems that nobody takes any notice of his opinions.

On one hand, the sentence above using "を" is detecting its change as the price went down or up. And here the PRICE is a research subject that we tend to focus on. And in any dictionary, "を"'s very first usage is like this: 他動的意味の動詞が表す動作・作用の向けられる対象を示す。Hence using "を" is more appropriate.

On the other hand, “に” has the following usages:

一、表時間（動作發生時的時間）(time)
 二、表歸著點（變換位置的到達點）(whereabouts)
 三、表存在場所（指人事物本身的存在場所）(exist)
 四、表指向場所 (指靜態動作的指向場所）(pointing to)
 五、表轉換結果（事物或狀態轉變的結果）(switch to another status)
 六、表對象（單向動作所指向的對象）(the thoughts about an object or an action that is about to be in effect)
 七、表次數（一個期間內包含的次數）(how many times)
 八、表目的（移動動詞的目的）(goal)
one's opinion is not easily changed, so using "に" is much more natural.

But the overall usages of these two characters in these situations are interchangeable. Minute as it is, no need to put too much energy into these.

それは私の見解です。あなたを助けることを望む。
以上です。